# Inapp browser basic authentication not working

Tags: android, android-webview, basic-authentication, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I have an url like `http://username:password@ipaddress:port//test/test.mjepd.cgi`.
It actually streams a camera in app browser.

However it works in laptop and computer not in mobile web view.
It simple does not load.

By going through some forums I came to know that passing basic authentication credentials is not supported in mobile in app browser webview.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Add the `Authorization` header to the request:

```
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
    webview.loadUrl(url, headers);
```

Option 2: Handle the authentication through a callback:

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            if (realm.equals(expectedRealm) && host.equals(ipaddress)) {
                handler.proceed(username, password);
            } else {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
```

Also: if you must use basic auth, do yourself a favor and use `https:`; don't send passwords in clear text.

Comment: This url calls up a camera that in turn starts streaming. It does not have OPTIONS enabled so I am unable to call this with headers. Also I am using ionic, the hybrid framework. it does not support onReceivedHttpAuthRequest with any of the available plugins.

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice the hybrid-mobile-app tag.  I've never developed with Ionic, or Cordova, or Angular.js.  I looked through a bunch of docs, and I am sure there is way to do this either through a custom plugin or a custom Angular module.  Hopefully somebody with Ionic experience can answer.  Another idea I had was to pass your credentials on query parameters in the URL and have the server/firewall rewrite the URL to move the credentials to the right place.  Apache mod_write does rewrite the URLs before authentication, so this seems like it should work.